# What do you call someone who bears a group of people ill-will?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Let's say that there is a person who bears a certain group of people ill-will, wishes something bad to happen to them. The group of people is not of any specific ethnicity or group. They just reside in a specific place. What would you call such a person ?

e.g. sentence - From the moment I laid eyes on you, I knew you were a/an _________ who bears us nothing but ill-will.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective?  Can you provide a sample sentence in which you would use the word you're looking for?

Comment: ***Biased***, ***prejudiced***. Not aware of any words specific to disliking the residents of a particular area, but I feel like there should be one. That must have been the original kind of prejudice; nobody likes the people who live on the other side of the river.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn: A noun is preferred. added a sample sentence

Comment: Informally, a *hater*.

Comment: "Antagonist," "malcontent," or "foe" might work, but the "specific place" bit is tough. Is that important, or is this just some arbitrary group of people?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a word for non-general but apparently unbigoted malevolence.

Comment: _Bigot_ is the usual English term. It doesn't mean anything about mustaches, however; it just means someone who is prejudiced against some social group.

Comment: @JohnLawler I would definitely suggest Bigot would be a very good possible answer to the question

Comment: The question seems slightly odd to me. The people are hated for no particular reason, just that they live in a particular place? They sound a bit like British football supporters. Sunderland people hate Newcastle people - for no definable reason, other that one lot support the Black Cats and the other the Magpies. Is that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: ........*snob*.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'bigot' is appropriate here. It implies that the person's ill will is irrational, or that they refuse to hear/understand the opinions of others... which is not stated in the question. Actually, 'hater', although informal and a bit of a neologism, is probably best... it doesn't imply any judgement about whether the hatred is rational/justified/informed or not.

Comment: "Grudge-holder" is probably about the closest you can come, unless you resort to a more pejorative term such as "bigot".

Comment: "Jingoist" and "chauvinist" are possibilities.

Comment: From the moment I laid eyes on you, I knew you were a bearer of animus.

Comment: The sample sentence seems to be a bit tautologous.   _________ who bears us nothing but ill-will. If the blank is supposed to be the person who bears ill will then it sounds repetitive.

Comment: or 'I knew you were evil incarnate!'

Answer (score 1):

enemy

1 : one that is antagonistic to another; especially : one seeking to injure, overthrow, or confound an opponent
[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enemy)

1.
a. One who feels hatred toward, intends injury to, or opposes another; a foe.
[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/enemy)

1A person who is actively opposed or hostile to someone or something.
[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enemy)

Using your sentence:

> From the moment I laid eyes on you, I knew you were a/an/our 'enemy'
>   who bears us nothing but ill-will.

I added the "our" option alongside a/an as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could say a *resenter*, a person who feels resentment.
Source:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resenter

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - ??!  The answer needs documentation, I'll grant you that, but where is Ross critiquing or requesting clarification?

Answer (score 0):

(1) There is no specific single word answer.

(2) In the real world, the context in which you use something like this will usually mean that you have to explain it further (negating the need for a single word) OR that there are already existing local terms that refer to those regions and their inhabitants.

Think of "yankee" being a negative southern US term for northerners or  "carpetbagger." I realize it's not exactly the same, but it captures the dynamic